# Getting value on the basis of Id from Enums in Javascript

Tags: javascript, enums

It has been quite sometime when I explored different ways of implementing **Enums** in **javaScript**

say I have an Enum names as `Medium`as

```
    Medium : {
            ONLINE : {id: 1, desc: "Online"},
            CREDIT : {id: 2, desc: "Credit Card"},
            DEBIT : {id: 3, desc: "Debit Card"},
            NETBANKING : {id: 4, desc: "Net Banking"}
   }
```

say I got an information that medium is 3.
Now from this information how can I get the details like description. In this case it should return "Debit card".

Searched a lot on internet but not able to get any lead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with [`Array#find`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjW8fOno6vUAhULtI8KHWZHBV0QFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Ffind&usg=AFQjCNEJXKz25jH7wLT1dX55f_XDZ9QiRg&sig2=kCIT5LCCV3Nn0yCrkJrBuA) method

```js
var   PaymentMedium ={
            ONLINE : {id: 1, desc: "Online"},
            CREDIT : {id: 2, desc: "Credit Card"},
            DEBIT : {id: 3, desc: "Debit Card"},
            NETBANKING : {id: 4, desc: "Net Banking"}
   }
   
   function get(id){
   return Object.values(PaymentMedium).find(a=> (a.id == id)).desc
   }
   console.log(get(3))
```

Answer (score 0):

The order of properties in a JavaScript objects aren't guaranteed, so you'd need to use an array if you want to specify the position.  See [this S.O question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order).

Alternatively, you could get the required property by using the id value within it? (See Prasad's answer above)